# Border crossing through links when the liks are floated to the left

Tags: html, css

So, I am coding website and I have a toolbar with links and some text floating to he left and the container (the class names toolbar-container) has a border on the bottom but the border is crossing through the text. I want everything to look the same, but I want the border below. The repository containing all the code is at: https://github.com/DigitalBlast/Digital-Blast/

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed that issue

Comment: You need to post the relevant, minimal markup here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is your friend.  Please post the code for a minimal example that will stand alone and recreate the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Without that your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Make sure that the code you include ***in your question*** is **Minimal** (only the code necessary to reproduce the problem), **Complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce the problem) and **Verifiable** (we should be able to reproduce the problem using only the code in your question, nothing less and nothing more).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="toolbar-container">
  <div class="toolbar-container-logo">
    Digital<span class="toolbar-container-logo-sub">Blast</span>
  </div>
  <div class="toolbar-container-home" onclick="window.location.href='home/index.html'">
    <h4>Home</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="toolbar-container-software" onclick="window.location.href='software/index.html'">
    <h4>Software</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="clear-left"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear-left {
  clear: left;
}
```

Comment: What does this do? How does it fix anything?

Comment: You should explain your answer and not just write code for him. That's not what SO is for.